# Install Lisk on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ubuntu, installation, blockchain, ethereum

I'm trying to install Lisk on my Ubuntu and it doesn't really work.

I tried two things :

Here : https://lisk.io/documentation/core/installation/binary-test-network

At the end at address http://localhost:7000/ i get an error : 
"cannot GET /",
nothing else. No error displayed during installation.

And here : https://github.com/LiskHQ/lisk

Same, no error during installation and on http://localhost:6380 i get the error : 
"-ERR wrong number of arguments for 'get' command"

No idea how to make it, i am not (yet) familiar with this technology, how can i do please ? Thank you.

Comment: Lisk Core does not respond to `/` endpoint. Assuming you are using version 0.9.x, try `http://localhost:7000/api/loader/status` to check if your node is running.